# how to get a list of unapply migrations in dotnet ef

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.1

I am having a bit of trouble trying to list all unapplied migrations using dotnet ef command.

Since I am working with other developers there are a few new migrations going in during each other development.

When I run `dotnet ef migrations list` it will list all available migrations.

Is there a way to find out which migrations is not applied?

Comment: If you have access to the DB, you could look in the __EFMigrationsHistory table. Which should contain all the applied migrations.

Comment: yes, I can manually do it, but I wonder if there is a better and automatic way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coming soon as issue [#577](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/577). Until then, you can get them programmatically using code like this:

```
var pendingMigrations = myDbContext.Database.GetPendingMigrations();
```